# Would this pateent apply to SMS in an Mobile Inbox too?

Tags: mobile, sms, us7475110, inbox, merge

In reference to the patent: [US7475110](https://www.google.com/patents/US7475110)

Would this apply to SMS in an Mobile Inbox too ? 
I mean if i want to club 2 messages from 2 different users into 1, then would this patent hold good or should there be a new patent for it ?